# Difference between LookaHead RegEx and other one?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Can anyone please let me know which is the best solution?

I'm trying to get the 5 to 10 characters, at least one letter, no special characters, characters in \w is acceptable.

and the second one is checking for minimum length 5 but not validating for maximum length. why?

```
    ^(?=.{5,10}$)(\w*[a-z]\w*)$

    ^(\w*[a-z]\w*){5,10}$
```

Thanks,
Viji

Comment: I'm not sure of what your question is. If you don't get an answer please give some more detail.

Comment: Hey Viji I agree with Bergi that performance for such a small regex task is probably irrelevant, nevertheless if you benchmark the solutions I'd be curious to know the results, would you please share them?

Comment: @zx81 : Bergi and you both answered my question. And I really appreciate the time you have spend to come up with the new regex and explanation.

Comment: @Viji If you like both of the answers equally, feel free to flip a coin to choose the answer to accept, I won't mind and I'm sure neither will Bergi. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the second one, the whole group `(\w*[a-z]\w*)` is allowed to be repeated from 5 to 10 times.

And in that group, you have any number of `\w` characters allowed.

What you might want to use instead is

```
^(?=.*?[a-z])\w{5,10}$
```

but your first expression is fine as well. I don't think there's an easy solution without lookahead.

Comment: thanks. then how to set the maximum limit in second expression? is this expression called greedy expr?

Comment: An whole expression is usually not called "greedy". The [`*` repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is greedy, yes.

Comment: ok. is there a way to set the maximum limit without using lookahead?

Comment: Doesn't .Net have lookaheads? [Here's a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4632786/1048572) that does similar and has an accepted answer with a lookahead as well...

Answer (score 2):

In the comments to Bergi's (correct) answer, you asked for a way to match your string without a lookahead.

Here is one. It's a neat regex trick, but it doesn't make the regex simpler than when you were using a lookahead.

```
^(?:([a-z])|[_0-9]){5,10}(?(1)|^)$
```

This will work in regex flavors that support conditionals, such as .NET, PCRE, Python and Ruby.

**How does it work?**

1. `(?:([a-z])|[_0-9])` matches exactly one character. To specify the characters, we use an alternation `|`. If the character is a letter, the parentheses in `([a-z])` capture it to Group 1.
2. The `{5,10}` quantifier make sure that we match the right number of characters
3. The `(?(1)|^)` is a conditional that checks if capture Group1 has been set. If it has been set (the left side of the `|`), no action is taken. If Group 1 has not been set (the right side of the `|`), that means we have not matched a single letter, and the `^` beginning of string assertion forces the regex to fail.

Comment: Isn't `(?!)` a lookahead as well?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. Please see revision, even neater. :)

Comment: What an abomination! +1 for cleverness. Hope this doesn't get used anywhere :-)

Comment: `Hope this doesn't get used anywhere` Neither do I. :) But as you probably know, this kind of construct is common practice (and necessary) when using balancing groups.